# TakeWhile filtering on <IEnumerable<IGrouping>> returns InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, loops, linq, exception, ienumerable

I have a `private IEnumerable<IGrouping<string MyClass>> myGrouping;`

And I am doing this with it:

```
foreach (IGrouping<string, MyClass> filteredGrouping in myGrouping.Select(x => x.TakeWhile(t => t.MyProperty != 0))) {

    string n = filteredGrouping.Key;

    // do things
}
```

Because I want to run the code in `foreach` only when `MyProperty` has value.

But my code causes the following exception:

> 'Unable to cast object of type 'd_217'[MyProject.MyFolder.MyClass]' to type 'System.Linq.IGrouping`2[Ssystem.String,MyProject.MyFolder.MyClass]'.'

What is wrong with my approach and how can I rectify it?

Comment: use var instead of ````IGrouping<string, MyClass>````

Comment: Instead of putting it directly into the foreach, what if you store it in a variable. It's easier to debug what the result of the Select is.

Comment: It's probably returning an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<MyClass>>`. So `filteredGrouping` will probably be `IEnumerable<MyClass>`

Comment: @Mohamed thanks! I did change it to var, but then I couldn't use the IGrouping key. So I worked around that, and now my code runs, but it is not working as intended. But that's beside the scope of this question, I guess..